# How to solve "npm is not recognised" in visual code?

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, npm, error-handling, npm-install

I have updated my path in enivronmental variables as *;C:/NFT/*

Still the termial is displaying this, **npm: The term 'npm' is not recognized as a name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or executable program. Check the spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and try again.**

What should I do now???

Comment: why did you use `C:/NFT/`? Maybe you have npm in different folder.

Answer (score 0):

> I have updated my path in enivronmental variables as `;C:/NFT/`

Please change to the following content to the environment variable correctly:

```
;C:\Program Files\nodejs\
```

Then reopen the CMD and use command `npm`